# basename "$0" not working

Tags: osx, basename

I have this command:

```
 base_name="$(basename "$0")";
```

and I am getting this error:

> basename: illegal option -- b
>
> usage: basename string [suffix]
>          basename [-a] [-s suffix] string [...]

anyone know what's going on with that?

Comment: @jeffschaller has a good answer, but what is your actual goal, to learn the name of the shell? https://askubuntu.com/questions/590899/how-do-i-check-which-shell-i-am-using/1022440#1022440

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My lucky guess would be that `$0` contains the string `-bash` and so your command becomes:

```
basename -bash
```

which `basename` interprets as a single-character option "b".  Change that to:

```
base_name="$(basename -- "$0")";
```

... so that `basename` is told to stop looking for options.

Comment: is this the case for non-OSX as well?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Any Unix.

Comment: coreutil's basename gets confused without it; AIX's handles it, but also honors `--` as end-of-options. I can't speak to others off-hand.